# How to show an input after doing $ajax->observeField

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a form with two inputs:

```
echo $this->Form->input('articulo_id', array('empty'=>'---Select---'));

echo $this->Form->input('numeral_id', array('empty'=>'---Select---', 'type'=>'hidden'));
```

When the first one changes state the second one gets updated and auto-populated; this is how it gets updated:

```
$options = array('url' => 'getArtNum', 'update' => 'EvidenciaNumeralId');

echo $ajax->observeField('EvidenciaArticuloId', $options);
```

The thing is that I need the second one to be shown after doing the update.
Is there a way to do it?

I know if I just delete the `'type'=>'hidden'` from the form the input will be shown but I need it to stay hidden until the first one change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late but maybe it helps other people with same problem.

You have to try [callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/view/211/Callback-Options):

```
$options['after'] = "$('EvidenciaNumeralId').show()";
echo $ajax->observeField('EvidenciaArticuloId', $options);
```

This should help.